# Java Android ContextCompat and ActivityCompat imports suddenly cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having an issue with a Java project that was previously working fine, until I loaded it and it cannot resolve the ActivityCompat and ContextCompat symbols all of a sudden.

How can I fix this?

There are some suggestions, `Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01', or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.` 
But I didn't change anything. How do I set this, will this fix the issue, and was this caused by some kind of update?

[image]

Comment: Android uses code names for each version of Android. 'UpsideDownCake' is for Android U which is still in beta. Check your targetSDK settings and library dependences in gradle (avoid the alpha for now). And if you are including source from a third-party library, check that it is the release version.

Comment: where exactly do I check for this? And how do I set it? I literally did not change anything in any of the settings files

Comment: Please include your `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle` file. Sounds like you have a dependency that includes a `+` that automatically upgrades the version...which is never what you want

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, suddenly out of the blue it gave me dozens of `Cannot resolve symbol X`.

I did the following:

1. Clean project - no impact
2. Closed and reopened - no impact immediately

However, after a few minutes, grade sync started, and took a fair amount of time and at the end of it resolved all symbols. Looking at the log I see some salient items:

```
2023-06-28 18:52:58,249 [      6]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------
2023-06-28 18:53:43,834 [  45591]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.g.p.AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivity - Up-to-date models found in the cache. Not invoking Gradle sync.
2023-06-28 18:54:57,608 [ 119365]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1
2023-06-28 18:55:00,203 [ 121960]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:00,203 [ 121960]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>
2023-06-28 18:55:00,323 [ 122080]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:00,323 [ 122080]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>
2023-06-28 18:55:00,710 [ 122467]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:00,710 [ 122467]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>
2023-06-28 18:55:00,985 [ 122742]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:00,986 [ 122743]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>
2023-06-28 18:55:01,675 [ 123432]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:01,675 [ 123432]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>
2023-06-28 18:55:01,705 [ 123462]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - getPackageName: failed to find packageName for library com.google.android.gms:play-services-fido:19.0.1@aar
2023-06-28 18:55:01,705 [ 123462]   INFO - #o.j.a.u.ViewLoader - loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project <ProjectName>

...

2023-06-28 19:01:04,591 [      5]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------
2023-06-28 19:01:32,269 [  27683]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Started scanning for indexing of <ProjectName>. Reason: On project open
2023-06-28 19:04:50,786 [ 226200]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Started scanning for indexing of <ProjectName>. Reason: On updated roots of library 'Kotlin Script dependencies'
2023-06-28 19:04:57,473 [ 232887]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Started scanning for indexing of <ProjectName>. Reason: Merged changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.6.0", "Library Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10", "Library Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.10", "Library Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0", "Library Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0", "Library Gradle: androidx.core:core:1.10.1@aar", "Library Gradle: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1@aar", "Library Gradle: com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0@aar", "Library Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.2.0@aar", "Library Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0@aar" and 1 iterators more with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.5.1@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test:runner:1.5.2@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test.services:storage:1.4.2@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test:annotation:1.0.1@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test:monitor:1.6.1@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test:core:1.5.0@aar" with changes in: "Library Gradle: androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5@aar"
2023-06-28 19:06:24,828 [ 320242]   INFO - #c.i.d.PerformanceWatcherImpl - Reindexing refreshed files of <ProjectName> took 76ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
```